# React Dropdown dynamic buttons with material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dropdown

I am trying to copy the parts inside black circles on the image below for training React and Material UI. My problem is that I am struggling a bit with which Material UI components to use... Any help or examples that looks like this are happily accepted!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some components from material-ui for composing the UI like what you asked for. You need to compose these components by yourself.

For components inside the long black circle, they can be from `selects`  https://mui.com/components/selects/. You can find different styles from this link.

For components inside another circle. They are `buttons`, `text_fields`, `chips`, and `cards`. Which can be found from
https://mui.com/components/buttons/ https://mui.com/components/text-fields/ https://mui.com/components/chips/ https://mui.com/components/cards/

Can't give an answer for the part of `Minerva Obj Name` without knowing how it is interacted.